# Recalculate list of linked objects

Tags: c#, .net, linked-list, reference

I have some kind of financial report, where each row is some object that depends on the previous one. I need to get the list of these objects. When I calculate each row, I need to analize its values and make some fixes if needed.

Here is my ReportRow class:

```
public class ReportRow 
{
    public ReportRow (ReportRow  previousRow)
    {
        PreviousRow = previousRow;
    }
    public ReportRow PreviousRow;

    private decimal? _bankRest;
    public decimal BankRest
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_bankRest.HasValue)
                _bankRest = PreviousRow.BankRest - CurrentInvestments;
            return _bankRest.Value;

        }
        set
        {
            _bankRest = value;
        }
    }
    public decimal CurrentInvestments => Sum1 + Sum3;
    public decimal Sum1 { get; set; }//here is some formula
    public decimal Sum3 { get; set; }//here is some other formula
}
```

This class is very simplified but, I think, it can help to understand the problem.
Here can be a situation when CurrentInvestments can get too big and BankRest will become negative. (CurrentInvestments has more complex formula and can become extra large).

Here is how I collect report data.

```
public void GetReport()
{
    ReportRow firstRaw = GetFirstRow();//here i somehow get first row to start calculation
    List<ReportRow> report = new List<ReportRow>(); //the full report
    ReportRow previous = firstRaw;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        ReportRow next = new ReportRow(previous);
        AnalizeAndFix(next);//Here is where I have a problem
        report.Add(next);
        previous = next; //current becomes previous for next iteration 
    }
}
```

I have a problem in AnalizeAndFix(next) function.
If current period's BankRest is negative (<0) I need to cancel the previous period CurrentInvestments (make CurrentInvestments = 0, which will get previous BankRest larger). If this doesn't help, I need to go two steps up and cancel that row investments as well. Then check currentRaw BankRest. I need to repeat this 6 times. If setting CurrentInvestments to 0 of six previous raws didn't help - throw an exceptions. And in total report all periods that were touched need to be updated. I managed to fix only one previous row, but I don't know how to do it 5 more times.
Here is code for my AnalizeAndFix

```
private void AnalizeAndFix(ref ReportRow current)
    {
        if (current.BankRest < 0)
        {
            int step = 0;
            while (current.BankRest < 0 || step < 6)
            {
                step++;
                var previous = current.PreviousRow;
                previous.CancellInvestments(); //I set CurrentInvestments to 0
                current = new ReportRow(previous); // create a new report based on recalculated previous
            }
        }
    }
```

If I use this aproach, the final report shows me recalculated current and previous rows as I want (I think). However I don't know how to do this 5 more times, so all affected rows will show changed in final report.
Or may be I need to rethink the whole system and do the stuff I need some other way?

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the linked list functionality from your `ReportRow` class and use [the LinkedList class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netframework-4.0) instead. This class comes with built-in methods for adding/removing nodes ([a node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlistnode-1?view=netframework-4.0) is an object that holds one of your rows plus pointers to the previous and next one) and to navigate to the previous and next node.